# Can an Oracle Database request a system crash (One Instance Crash)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, crash, solaris

I am Junior Database Administrator at a Bank and there was an issue that caused the  Oracle Database Instance one to crash (We have two instances). So the system rebooted itself and everything is working fine now. But the bank's DBA consultant said the Database requested the system crash. I tried to google on it but couldn't find any thing on it.

My question is, can oracle db request a system crash (crash the instance that has the issue) if the db is experiencing issue with the OS?

FYI, It is running Oracle RAC Grid Infrastructure

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you be a bit more specific in your question? Normally you have: `1.` Hardware, `2.` Operating System, `3.a.` Oracle Database Instance, `3.b.` Oracle Listener. However, you are referring to an OS instance. Please [edit] your question and add more details. Please also consider reading up on [Troubleshooting After a System Crashes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E61000/gntjw.html) (Oracle Solaris Docs). Thanks. Anything is possible, but you would probably need a consultant to analyse the crash dump files.

Comment: Never heard of such a "request".

Comment: ...and what Gerard said. An operating system crash can be ***caused*** by an Oracle Database crash/incident. It is however highly unlikely. What "normally" happens is that an Oracle Database instance crashes. This can be analysed with the [Automatic Diagnostic Repository Command Interpreter (ADCRI)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-DC5744C7-FAC0-436B-99D5-DBD45B66930B.htm#SUTIL700) tool.

Comment: If you are dealing with Oracle RAC (which it sounds like maybe you are) then Oracle Grid Infrastructure (aka Oracle Clusterware) _can_ reboot a cluster node if the local instance encounters a problem. It is a controlled reboot, though and not a "system crash". This can happen when a node loses communication on the cluster interconnect with other nodes, or if the local database instance crashes.

Comment: Maybe he meant that SMON or PMON terminated an unstable background process, and this led to the instance being shut down. It happens sometimes in times of instability or bad performance or hardware failure. This also leads to one or more core dumps of the bad processes on the OS.